# environment variables not recognized in docker compose

Tags: docker, variables, docker-compose

Environment variables defined in docker-compose.yml are not set.

```
services:
  service1:
    image: alpine
    environment:
      - VAR1:H
      - VAR2:HI
    command:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - |
        echo $VAR1
        echo $VAR2
```

This outputs:

```
$ docker compose up
WARN[0000] The "VAR1" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "VAR2" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
[+] Running 1/0
 ⠿ Container compose-service1-1  Recreated                                                                                                                                                                              0.1s
Attaching to compose-service1-1
compose-service1-1  |
compose-service1-1  |
compose-service1-1 exited with code 0
```

Docker Compose version v2.12.0

Comment: I tried both, same result. Here's the documentation showing that either should work, but neither does. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Envrionment variables can be either passed with map syntax or array syntax, see:

```
# Array syntax
services:
  service1:
    image: alpine
    environment:
      - VAR1=H
      - VAR2=HI
    command:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - |
        echo $$VAR1
        echo $$VAR2
```

Or,

```
# Map syntax
services:
  service1:
    image: alpine
    environment:
      VAR1: "H"
      VAR2: "HI"
    command:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - |
        echo $$VAR1
        echo $$VAR2
```

Then, you have to use `$$`.  As using `echo $VAR1` makes docker-compose look for the variables from your host's environment.

See:

- https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment
- https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#interpolation

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
 services:
  service1:
    image: alpine
    environment:
     VAR1: "H"
     VAR2: "HI"
    command:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - |
        echo "$${VAR1}"
        echo "$${VAR2}"
```

Comment: Also correct but @Fcmam5 was first. You get a vote up.